# Python: Conditional class arguments

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following `User` class

```
class User(db.Model, CommonFields):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "metadata"}

    email = db.Column(db.String)
    name = db.Column(db.String

    client = db.relationship("Clients", secondary=client_group)
```

I am inserting into the DB during the following function

```
def create_user(
    email: str,
    name: str,
    client_group: str
):

client_group = Client.get_client(client_group)

if client_group:
        user = User(
             email=email,
             name=name,
             client=[client_group]
        ) 
    else:
        user = User(
            email=email,
            name=name,
        )

    user = user.insert()
    return user_schema.dump(user)
```

Now this works, but it's very repetitive.

My question is there a way to do this to make it less repetitive?

A way to have conditional class arguments without repeating it in an if statement?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of `create_user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to pass named parameters dynamically. Then you can conditionally add an item to the dictionary.

```
user_dict = {"email": email, "name": name}
if client_group:
    user_dict["client"] = [client_group]
user = User(**user_dict)
```